# How to know the last button clicked in android using sharedpreference?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have two buttons, Now how I can know the last button clicked using sharedpreference when start the activity again ?

the code:

> private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
>
> SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

init in onCreate:

> > sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
> >
> > editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

I tried to do this but absolutely wrong way

```
        if (sharedPreferences.getString("lamp", "on")) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "onnnn", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (sharedPreferences.getString("lamp", "off")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "offfff", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

first button

```
 public void lampOff(View view) {
    Log.d(tag, "lampOFF");

    lamp_notConnected_Image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    lamp_Connected_Image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



    editor.putString("lamp", "off");
    editor.commit();
}
```

seconde button:

```
 public void lampOn(View view) {
    Log.d(tag, "lampO");

    lamp_notConnected_Image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    lamp_Connected_Image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    editor.putString("lamp", "on");
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: so... what have you tried? I see you're writing the last state to shared pref, but where's the code that reads the shared pref and does the necessary logic?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your condition `if (sharedPreferences.getString("lamp", "on"))`, you aren't comparing this string to anything, either use

```
if (sharedPreferences.getString("lamp", "on").equals("on"))
```

or

save the value as boolean `editor.putBoolean("lamp", true);`, then you can compare the way you were doing: `if (sharedPreferences.getString("lamp", true))`

Note that here ("lamp", "on") the fist parameter is the identification, and the second is the default value, in case nothing is stored there yet.

See more in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the shared preference value in onCreate method like:

```
if (sharedPreferences.getString("lamp", "off").equals("on")) { //assumed "off" as default
    Toast.makeText(this, "onnnn", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // on button is pressed last time
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(this, "offfff", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // off button is pressed last time or no button press so far
}
```

Comment: onCreate method will be called when activity is opening